# When using cache busting what happens to cached files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

When we are using cache busting for CSS and Javascript files, let's say by changing filename or query string, what happens to already cached file in user's hard disk? Will that old cached file be deleted after caching newer version? Or browser holds copy of older and newer versions of file?

Answer (score 1):

The browser will keep the old cached files. It doesn't know anything about cache busters, these are just a bunch of different URLs. It has no way of knowing that you're never going to request the old URL again, so it doesn't know that the cache is not needed.

If the cache gets too full, it will delete old files, so don't worry about it.

Comment: OTOH, you need to be aware that this means “busting the cache” once does not mean the original cache is now gone. If you request the original, non-busting URL again, you’ll get the older cached version again.

Comment: @deceze The usual way that cache busters are used is that you *always* add it to the URL, so there's no "non-busting URL" in the first place.

Comment: Typically yes, but here's a counter example: you have a REST resource which is cached, you POST a request whereupon said resource is being updated. It can be tricky to bust the cache of that resource when you *know* it has been updated, but also continue to cache it appropriately.

Comment: You should have a cache buster in the URL you use to retrieve the resource, so you never use a cached value.

Comment: What if I *want* to use a cached value (because performance), unless I explicitly *know* the resource has been updated?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would know that, since there's no API to let you see when the resource was cached. If you're talking about retrieving it in the same browser session, you could just use a JavaScript variable and not fetch the resource at all.

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking of too convoluted examples, you're probably right.